# Error While installing Calico CNI

Tags: networking, kubernetes, calico, kubectl

I have a Kubernetes cluster with 1+1 configuration .

I used the following steps to install Calico

```
curl https://docs.projectcalico.org/manifests/calico-typha.yaml -o calico.yaml
kubectl apply -f calico.yaml
```

But the pods are not running

```
an001@mastercal:~$ kubectl get pods -A
NAMESPACE      NAME                                       READY   STATUS       RESTARTS   AGE
kube-flannel   kube-flannel-ds-dz5xb                      1/1     Running      0          2d21h
kube-flannel   kube-flannel-ds-x9zjt                      1/1     Running      0          2d21h
kube-system    calico-kube-controllers-5bb7768754-m8pbj   0/1     Running      0          25s
kube-system    calico-node-kkb4k                          0/1     Init:Error   1          25s
kube-system    calico-node-qfvwg                          0/1     Init:Error   1          25s
kube-system    calico-typha-69c485b8c4-4lvzt              0/1     Running      0          25s
kube-system    coredns-f9fd979d6-2wtzb                    1/1     Running      0          2d21h
kube-system    coredns-f9fd979d6-qhqp4                    1/1     Running      0          2d21h
kube-system    etcd-mastercal                             1/1     Running      0          2d21h
kube-system    kube-apiserver-mastercal                   1/1     Running      0          2d21h
kube-system    kube-controller-manager-mastercal          1/1     Running      0          2d21h
kube-system    kube-proxy-4qrbq                           1/1     Running      0          2d21h
kube-system    kube-proxy-xhkg6                           1/1     Running      0          2d21h
kube-system    kube-scheduler-mastercal                   1/1     Running      0          2d21h


an001@mastercal:~$ kubectl get events -n kube-system
LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON              OBJECT                                          MESSAGE
53s         Normal    Scheduled           pod/calico-kube-controllers-5bb7768754-m8pbj    Successfully assigned kube-system/calico-kube-controllers-5bb7768754-m8pbj to workercal
51s         Normal    Pulled              pod/calico-kube-controllers-5bb7768754-m8pbj    Container image "docker.io/calico/kube-controllers:v3.25.0" already present on machine
50s         Normal    Created             pod/calico-kube-controllers-5bb7768754-m8pbj    Created container calico-kube-controllers
50s         Normal    Started             pod/calico-kube-controllers-5bb7768754-m8pbj    Started container calico-kube-controllers
1s          Warning   Unhealthy           pod/calico-kube-controllers-5bb7768754-m8pbj    Readiness probe failed: Error initializing datastore: Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/apis/crd.projectcalico.org/v1/clusterinformations/default": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: connect: no route to host
5s          Warning   Unhealthy           pod/calico-kube-controllers-5bb7768754-m8pbj    Liveness probe failed: Error initializing datastore: Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/apis/crd.projectcalico.org/v1/clusterinformations/default": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: connect: no route to host
53s         Normal    SuccessfulCreate    replicaset/calico-kube-controllers-5bb7768754   Created pod: calico-kube-controllers-5bb7768754-m8pbj
53s         Normal    ScalingReplicaSet   deployment/calico-kube-controllers              Scaled up replica set calico-kube-controllers-5bb7768754 to 1
52s         Normal    Scheduled           pod/calico-node-kkb4k                           Successfully assigned kube-system/calico-node-kkb4k to mastercal
52s         Normal    Pulled              pod/calico-node-kkb4k                           Container image "docker.io/calico/cni:v3.25.0" already present on machine
52s         Normal    Created             pod/calico-node-kkb4k                           Created container upgrade-ipam
51s         Normal    Started             pod/calico-node-kkb4k                           Started container upgrade-ipam
26s         Normal    Pulled              pod/calico-node-kkb4k                           Container image "docker.io/calico/cni:v3.25.0" already present on machine
26s         Normal    Created             pod/calico-node-kkb4k                           Created container install-cni
26s         Normal    Started             pod/calico-node-kkb4k                           Started container install-cni
7s          Warning   BackOff             pod/calico-node-kkb4k                           Back-off restarting failed container
52s         Normal    Scheduled           pod/calico-node-qfvwg                           Successfully assigned kube-system/calico-node-qfvwg to workercal
51s         Normal    Pulled              pod/calico-node-qfvwg                           Container image "docker.io/calico/cni:v3.25.0" already present on machine
51s         Normal    Created             pod/calico-node-qfvwg                           Created container upgrade-ipam
51s         Normal    Started             pod/calico-node-qfvwg                           Started container upgrade-ipam
27s         Normal    Pulled              pod/calico-node-qfvwg                           Container image "docker.io/calico/cni:v3.25.0" already present on machine
27s         Normal    Created             pod/calico-node-qfvwg                           Created container install-cni
27s         Normal    Started             pod/calico-node-qfvwg                           Started container install-cni
12s         Warning   BackOff             pod/calico-node-qfvwg                           Back-off restarting failed container
53s         Normal    SuccessfulCreate    daemonset/calico-node                           Created pod: calico-node-kkb4k
52s         Normal    SuccessfulCreate    daemonset/calico-node                           Created pod: calico-node-qfvwg
52s         Normal    Scheduled           pod/calico-typha-69c485b8c4-4lvzt               Successfully assigned kube-system/calico-typha-69c485b8c4-4lvzt to workercal
51s         Normal    Pulling             pod/calico-typha-69c485b8c4-4lvzt               Pulling image "docker.io/calico/typha:v3.25.0"
46s         Normal    Pulled              pod/calico-typha-69c485b8c4-4lvzt               Successfully pulled image "docker.io/calico/typha:v3.25.0" in 5.877965128s
45s         Normal    Created             pod/calico-typha-69c485b8c4-4lvzt               Created container calico-typha
45s         Normal    Started             pod/calico-typha-69c485b8c4-4lvzt               Started container calico-typha
8s          Warning   Unhealthy           pod/calico-typha-69c485b8c4-4lvzt               Readiness probe failed: Get "http://localhost:9098/readiness": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9098: connect: connection refused
9s          Warning   Unhealthy           pod/calico-typha-69c485b8c4-4lvzt               Liveness probe failed: Get "http://localhost:9098/liveness": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9098: connect: connection refused
52s         Normal    SuccessfulCreate    replicaset/calico-typha-69c485b8c4              Created pod: calico-typha-69c485b8c4-4lvzt
53s         Normal    ScalingReplicaSet   deployment/calico-typha                         Scaled up replica set calico-typha-69c485b8c4 to 1
```

How do I fix this ???

```
an001@mastercal:~$ kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://10.128.0.7:6443
KubeDNS is running at https://10.128.0.7:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
```